# A simple problem of linear algebra in infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a vector space (of infinite dimension) and $u : E \rightarrow E$. Suppose that $E/u(E)$ has finite dimension. Is it true then that this dimension is equal to $\dim \ker u$ ?

In finite dimension the rank theorem says yes. But here $E$ is typically infinite-dimensional. I realize it is still true that there is an isomorphism $\overline{u} : E/\ker u \rightarrow u(E)$, so I guess if we could prove that $E/(E/\ker u)) \simeq \ker u$ it would be enough.

EDIT : I'm not sure if this is relevant, but in my situation there is a (Banach) topology on $E$ and $u$ is continuous. Maybe this is important if we need to have direct spaces. However the question is purely algebraic, so I don't really know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't necessarily true. One of the main novel aspects of infinite-dimensional vector spaces is that they can be *isomorphic* to proper subspaces, i.e. $u$ may map $E$ onto $D\subsetneq E$ with no kernel. This is essentially no different that the set theoretic fact that infinite sets are in bijection with proper subsets.

For a concrete example, consider the vector space $\Bbb{R}[X]$ of real polynomials and have $u(p)=pX$. $u$ has no kernel, but the one-dimensional subspace of constant polynomials is missing from the image. It doesn't matter that your $E$ is a Banach space, as similar examples are then forthcoming.

Comment: I see. I guess even in a Banach space it needs not be true (cf my edit), because we could take for instance a shift on $l^1(\mathbb{N})$...

Comment: Yep, that would do.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample but this time: $dim ker u > dim(E/u(E))$.

Consider $E$ to be teh space of all polynomials with real or complex coefficients and consider $u$ to be the derivative operator. The image is the entire space while kernel is non-empty.

$$ u(a_{0} + \cdots + a_{n}x^{n}) = a_{1} + 2a_{2}x + \cdots + na_{n}x^{n-1}$$